# Different view for different user type in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Currently, I'm doing a react native project with expo, and I want to make 2 user type in my app (for example: student and lecturer). What is the best approach to save the user type?

Comment: You can improve this question by being more specific.  Broad, opinion-based questions are likely to get closed by moderators.  Propose some approaches.  Rather than asking what is best, detail what you expect from your solution and ask which proposed approach is most likely to lead to your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The things you want to google for managing state in a react native app are: react native async storage, react state storage, redux, react hooks, redux alternatives.  That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can save these type of information in react native ***async storage***.
 Let say for Student you save 1 and for lecturer you can save 2. But remember async storage always takes string as input, so don't forget to convert when saving or retrieving. Based on that you can check currently which user is accessing the app and then you have to render that view only.

**Sample code for storing data :**

```
storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

**Reading data :**

```
getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

**Finally you can make conditional view rendering just like below:**

```
tempUserType ===1 ? <code view for student> : <code view for lecturer>
```

> Here you can read more :-
>   https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

I hope this helps..... Thanks :)